# Spring MVC NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I'm following the spring tutorial series on caveofprogramming.com, I'm trying to hook up the controller to the database, I've followed everything to a T, when I submit the form I get

```
"HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.javaTypeToSqlParameterType(Ljava/lang/Class;)I"
```

The rest of the error page looks as follows:

type Exception report

```
message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.javaTypeToSqlParameterType(Ljava/lang/Class;)I

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.javaTypeToSqlParameterType(Ljava/lang/Class;)I
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1275)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:951)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:951)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:853)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.javaTypeToSqlParameterType(Ljava/lang/Class;)I
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource.getSqlType(BeanPropertySqlParameterSource.java:101)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlParameterList(NamedParameterUtils.java:415)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:340)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:283)
    com.merlin.spring.web.dao.OffersDAO.create(OffersDAO.java:58)
    com.merlin.spring.web.service.OffersService.create(OffersService.java:26)
    com.merlin.spring.web.controllers.OffersController.doCreate(OffersController.java:70)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:672)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:82)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:951)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:853)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.33 logs.
```

Apache Tomcat/8.0.33

Suggestions appreciated.

This is my POM, I cant see any conflicting versions of spring?

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.merlin.spring.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>offers</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>  
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Is all jars are copied to `lib` Folder of Your Project War. ?? @schnimmy

Comment: See this for a working project sample https://github.com/tgkprog/springHealthCare/ its multi module but compiles if u switch off testing (for that need to set up db too details in read me)

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I'm currently using tomcat through eclipse. but every dependency i've added through maven has the corresponding jar(s) under maven dependencies

Comment: @schnimmy then problem might be occurred due to `Spring` Jars Versioning Imcompatibility ..

Thank You.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap so which jars are incompatible with each other? I'm following a tutorial and he has pretty similar versions of everything...

Answer (score 3):

This type of Exceptions occurs when you mix different Spring versions. Example you have Spring Core version X but Spring Data version Y which are incompatible. Please try to use similar and compatible versions to fix this issue/.

Comment: I attached the pom, i cant see conflicting versions?

Comment: Look at BOM, there are scenarios when what you are referring needs some other spring component...

Comment: look at https://github.com/anthavio/anthavio-maven-poms/blob/master/spring-framework-bom.pom

Comment: @tgkprog whats the BOM?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest when using multiple spring dependencies also use this property for version, etc.:

```
<spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
```